# Refactoring Dynamic Approach for Optimal Binary Search Tree

Tags: c, algorithm, dynamic-programming

I am very new to the concept of Dynamic Programing and CS in general. I am teaching myself by reading lectures posted online, watching videos and solving problems posted on websites such as GeeksforGeeks and Hacker Rank.

**Problem**

Given input

```
3 25 30 5

where 3 =  #of keys

25 = frequency of key 1

30 = frequency of key 2

5  = frequency of key 3
```

I am to print the minimum cost if each key is arranged in a optimized manner. This is a optimal binary search tree problem and I found a solution on geeks for geeks that sort of does something similar.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <limits.h>

// A utility function to get sum of array elements freq[i] to freq[j]
int sum(int freq[], int i, int j);

/* A Dynamic Programming based function that calculates minimum cost of
   a Binary Search Tree. */
int optimalSearchTree(int keys[], int freq[], int n)
{
    /* Create an auxiliary 2D matrix to store results of subproblems */
    int cost[n][n];

    /* cost[i][j] = Optimal cost of binary search tree that can be
       formed from keys[i] to keys[j].
       cost[0][n-1] will store the resultant cost */

    // For a single key, cost is equal to frequency of the key
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
        cost[i][i] = freq[i];

    // Now we need to consider chains of length 2, 3, ... .
    // L is chain length.
    for (int L=2; L<=n; L++)
    {
        // i is row number in cost[][]
        for (int i=0; i<=n-L+1; i++)
        {
            // Get column number j from row number i and chain length L
            int j = i+L-1;
            cost[i][j] = INT_MAX;

            // Try making all keys in interval keys[i..j] as root
            for (int r=i; r<=j; r++)
            {
               // c = cost when keys[r] becomes root of this subtree
               int c = ((r > i)? cost[i][r-1]:0) + 
                       ((r < j)? cost[r+1][j]:0) + 
                       sum(freq, i, j);
               if (c < cost[i][j])
                  cost[i][j] = c;
            }
        }
    }
    return cost[0][n-1];
}

// A utility function to get sum of array elements freq[i] to freq[j]
int sum(int freq[], int i, int j)
{
    int s = 0;
    for (int k = i; k <=j; k++)
       s += freq[k];
    return s;
}

// Driver program to test above functions
int main()
{
    int keys[] = {0,1,2};
    int freq[] = {34, 8, 50};
    int n = sizeof(keys)/sizeof(keys[0]);
    printf("Cost of Optimal BST is %d ", optimalSearchTree(keys, freq, n));
    return 0;
}
```

However in this solution they are also taking input of the "keys", but it seems they have no impact on the final answer, as they shouldn't. Only the frequency of how many time each key is searched for matters.

For simplicity sake and understanding this dynamic approach, I was wondering how can I possibly modify this solution so that it takes its input in the format shown above and prints the result.

Comment: I don't understand the description of the problem. What exactly do you mean by 'arranged in an optimized manner'?

Comment: The optimal binary search tree problem is about constructing a binary search tree that minimizes the average cost of a search based on a given frequency of searches for each key.  When the frequencies are all the same, any minimal-depth (i.e. balanced) tree will do, but when the frequencies differ then the optimal tree will tend to cluster the more frequently-searched keys near the root, and may as a result be unbalanced.  The actual tree is not an output in this particular case, only a measure of the average cost of searching it.

Comment: @Codor John has posted an excellent description. I apologize if i was unclear. Apparently google uses something similar to store their search keywords. Obviously it must be much more complex but this is the fundamental idea.

Comment: Thanks, that was quite insightful!

Comment: Note, by the way, that it is not true that "*Only* the frequency of how many time each key is searched for matters" (emphasis added).  Since you want to consider only *search* trees, the order of the keys / frequencies matters, even though the specific key values do not.

Comment: Note, too, that the code you posted appears to be buggy.  The loop `for (int i=0; i<=n-L+1; i++){...}` wants to cover all values of `i` such that `i+L-1 < n` (so that `i+L-1` is a valid index in the `freq` array), but it goes too far by one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The function you presented does have a `keys` parameter, but it does not use it.  You could remove it altogether.

---

**Edit**: in particular, since function `optimalSearchTree()` does not use its `keys` parameter *at all*, removing that argument requires changing only the function signature (...

```
int optimalSearchTree(int freq[], int n)
```

...) and the one call of that function.  Since you don't need the keys for this particular exercise, though, you can altogether remove them from the main program, too, to give you:

```
int main()
{
    int freq[] = {25, 30, 5};
    int n = sizeof(freq)/sizeof(freq[0]);
    printf("Cost of Optimal BST is %d ", optimalSearchTree(freq, n));
    return 0;
}
```

(substituting the frequency values you specified for the ones in the original code)

---

The function does, however, assume that the frequencies are given in order of increasing key.  It needs at least the relative key order to do its job, because otherwise you cannot construct a *search* tree.  If you were uncomfortable with the idea that the key values are unknown, you could interpret the code to be using indices into the `freq[]` array as aliases for the key values.  That works because a consequence of the assumption described above is that `x` -> `keys[x]` is a 1:1, *order-preserving* mapping from integers `0` ... `n - 1` to whatever the actual keys are.

If the function could not assume the frequencies were initially given in increasing order by key, then it could first use the keys to sort the frequencies into that order, and then proceed as it does now.

Comment: I thought so too but when i remove this line  i get a different answer.
                       sum(freq, i, j);

Comment: Thanks for your answer also i was wondering is it possible for your to post a refactored code. For someone new like me its easier to understand a code that has only the required.

Comment: Yes, you get a different answer if you remove the term `sum(freq, i, j)` from the cost calculation.  That has to do with the frequencies (argument `freq`), not the keys.

Comment: I have edited my answer to show exactly what it would look like to remove the `keys` argument.

Comment: Thanks, just a question dosen't it also call the sum utility function to add up all the keys? does that not affect the final result?

Comment: @Learner, no, the code you posted does not do that.  What makes you think it does?  The `keys` argument does not appear *anywhere* in the body of function `optimalSearchTree()`.  The `sum()` function is used to add up frequencies, not keys.

Comment: For some reason i just tried to run some sample inputs and it is not giving the expected output..

Comment: @Learner, I can't really respond to your test results without knowing what input you tried and what the results were.  The code does give the result I expect for the few very small test cases I tried it on.